# Confusion with 'events' and mutually excusive

Tags: probability

Suppose two events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive then we say that $P$ ($A \cap B)=0$. In my knowledge event is the outcomes delivered when we preform a task. So in the above line, when two events are mutually exclusive, does that mean  any outcome obtained in any one event is different from outcomes obtained in other event? Is that what we use to identify any two events (mutually exclusive, exhaustive etc ).

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  In the set up, one imagines that there is a trial and that, after the trial, we will be able to say whether a given event happened or not.  To say the two events are mutually exclusive means that if you tell me that $A$ happened, then I know that $B$ did not and conversely (granted, for continuous distributions we may replace "did not happen" with "happened with probability $0$").  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, when you do a task (experiment) there are a set of possible outcomes S. Viewed this way, events are subsets of S. Mutually exclusive events (subsets) have no outcomes in common i.e an empty intersection in terms of subsets. Put in real terms, when one event happens the other cannot happen if they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Just to be clear, given that the events are mutually exclusive, $A\cap B=\emptyset$ (the intersection is the empty set); but the _probability_ is always a number, in this case $P(A\cap B) = 0$ (zero). It's not clear what you meant by "phie".

Comment: an event is a subset of the sample space. See [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Event_(probability_theory)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of drawing one playing card from a shuffled deck.

The events *drawing a 5* and *drawing a 7* are "mutually exclusive" ... both cannot happen at the same time.

On the other hand, *drawing a 5* and *drawing a diamond* are not mutually exclusive.  They could both happen at the same time: if we draw the 5 of diamonds.

Comment: Basically an event happens if any one or more outcome of that event is associated with the sample space so the logic that drawing a 5 and getting diamond is not exclusive is bcos we can draw both of them at once which will mean they both are happening and hence are not exclusive ,right?